# Reading a TXT with commas into individual cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have a txt file that has the following data example

hz,test1,test2,test3,test4,test5,

```
1,#,#,#,#,#,
2,#,#,#,#,#,
3,#,#,#,#,#,
4,#,#,#,#,#,
5,#,#,#,#,#,
6,#,#,#,#,#,
7,#,#,#,#,#,
```

.
.
etc

So each test as a reading at the 1,2,3,4,5 frequencies

but when I use my code it reads all the text into the first column instead of each being in separate columns. I thought the "," were supposed to divide it up so each section that is between commas goes in a separate columns and rows?

right now looks like this
[image]

Id like it to look like 
[image]

**Code:**

```
Dim DataFileName As String
Dim DFNamePath As String
Dim Handle As String
Dim i As Integer

i = 2

DataFileName = Cells(1, 2).Value

DFNamePath = "C:\Users\aholiday\Desktop\Data Dump\" & DataFileName & ".txt"

If MsgBox("Import RF Data?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then

    Open DFNamePath For Input As #1
    Do Until EOF(1)
        Input #1, Handle
        Cells(i, 1) = Handle
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    Close #1

    Else
    Exit Sub
End If
```

**I also get a runtime error 62 input past end of file during the loop, I think on the loop last pass**

Comment: Your code doesn't parse anything. Why don't you just rename it to csv and open it in Excel?

Comment: The testing software im getting the data from only out puts txt files, so unless if I can write a code to change txt to cvs. if that's possible?? still not sure how to use it

Comment: I'm attempting to parse right now. Is that the best way to achieve what I am trying to do? When I used the method above in my class it worked, but the data was laid out differently in the txt file. and I feel im missing a step..

Comment: If you want to put this into a new workbook, you could use the `Workbooks.OpenText` method which will allow you to parse the data as if it were a .csv file.  Or to do it manually, open the file with `Data Ribbon/Get External Data Tab/From Text` which will also open the `Text Import Wizard`.

Comment: You can also open it programmatically into an existing workbook by using the `ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can readily split the imported TXT once it arrives in the worksheet with the [Range.TextToColumns method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193593.aspx).

```
Sub split_Import()

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False  '<~~ take the traing wheels off
    With Worksheets("Sheet4")
        With .Columns(1)
            .TextToColumns Destination:=.Cells(1), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                           TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
                           Comma:=True, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, _
                           Space:=False, Other:=False, _
                           FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), _
                                            Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1))
        End With
    End With
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Your data is pretty straightforward so it should not be necessary to set any of the [xlColumnDataType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb241018%28v=office.12%29.aspx) FieldInfo values beyond a *General* output.

**Direct [Workbooks.OpenText method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837097.aspx)**

With an unknown number of columns, the [Workbooks.OpenText method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837097.aspx) may be a better option. Note its close resemblance to the [Range.TextToColumns method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193593.aspx). The array of FieldInfo [xlColumnDataType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb241018%28v=office.12%29.aspx)s is optional.

```
Sub split_Import()
    Dim fn As String, fp As String, ws As Worksheet

    fp = Environ("TMP") & Chr(92)      '<~~ set the TXT source folder
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet3")      '<~~ set destination worksheet

    With ws
        fn = .Cells(1, 1).Value2 & ".txt"
        Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=fp & fn, startrow:=2, DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                           TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
                           Comma:=True, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, _
                           Space:=False, Other:=False, local:=False
        With ActiveWorkbook
            With .Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
                ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) = .Value
            End With
            .Close False
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Note that I have discarded the header (e.g. **startrow:=2**) to match the first of your data images. Set to `startrow:=1` if you want to retain the header.

Be aware that I had some trouble with your merged cells interfering in locating the first empty row in column A. If you plan to keep them, you may have to make adjustments.

Comment: Will this work with 30,000 rows long and an unknown number of parts (columns)? or do I need to add a loop with I integer? also why is it sheet 4?

Comment: ①Yes, it will work with 30K rows.② The number of columns need to be determined beforehand and the routine adjusted to suit. If you have an idea of the maximum number of columns you will ever reach, you can set it for that. Too many doesn't matter but too few does.③ It is **Sheet4** because that is what I used to test it on.

Comment: Ok sweet, Where do I edit the amount of columns in the above code, isn't it `With .Columns(1)` right?

Comment: Please see additional method added.